# Recommendation for Open Source cache in C++

Tags: c++, caching

I need a caching library in C++ that acts a bit like [Guave's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) Loading Cache.

It should include the following:

- non-blocking access
- time based eviction
- size based eviction

I have looked at the STL, Boost and searched around but I am unable to find anything with this functionality.

Comment: I must admit I would immediately think memcached here, however it's more suited to multiple servers sharing. I don't know if there is an in-process version.

Comment: All you really need is a hash table and two doubly linked lists to implement a cache efficiently. Go look up in your operating systems book or on the web about how to implement an LRU cache, then you can likely extrapolate a solution for evicting based on size and time.

Comment: @selbie, I am aware that I could write this myself, but ideally I would like to find a mature, well tested library that has been used by many different projects and is "battle hardened".

Comment: Wish this hadn't been closed, I've got the same question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/). I believe its [caching framework](http://pocoproject.org/slides/140-Cache.pdf) will suit your needs.

```
ExpireLRUCache<int, string> cache(
                              1024,  // cacheSize
                              600000 // expiration (10 minutes)
);

cache.add( 1, "Cached string 1" );
cache.add( 10, "Cached string 10" );

Sleep( 601000 );

Shared_ptr<string> pVal = cache.get( 10 );
assert( pVal.isNull() ); // the element has expired
```

Comment: this comes close to what I need thanks. I do also need it to be non-blocking but perhaps I'm going to have to provide that myself. I shall leave the question open for now in the hope that it might exist already.